# Adding points from JSON to ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: geojson, android, json, arcgis-android

I am new to Android, the ArcGIS Platform and ArcGIS for Android.

I need to load points (offline) from a JSON file (GeoJSON) onto the map which displays  a local Tile Package (*.tpk) and shapefile.

Comment: The following tread on ArcGIS Resources forms discuss how to bring in GeoJSON into ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65695-from-geojson-data-to-featurelayer

Comment: it's not what i want. I need the Code to Load a point or point from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically we don't support shapefiles with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android, but it can be done.  Concerning loading points from a json file you need to parse the geojson file.

```
// Making the request and getting the response
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);

// Converting the response stream to string   
HttpEntity jsonentity = res.getEntity();
InputStream in = jsonentity.getContent();
// string representation of json
String json_str = convertStreamToString(in);

JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(json_str);
JSONArray feature_arr = jsonobj.getJSONArray("features");

// Getting the coordinates and projecting them to map's spatial
// reference            
JSONObject obj_geometry = feature_arr.getJSONObject(i)
    .getJSONObject("geometry");
double lon = Double.parseDouble(obj_geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates")
    .get(0).toString());
double lat = Double.parseDouble(obj_geometry.getJSONArray("coordinates")
    .get(1).toString());
Point point = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(
    new Point(lon, lat), SpatialReference.create(4326),
    mMapView.getSpatialReference());

// Add point graphic to the graphic layer
graphicsLayer.addGraphic(new Graphic(point, symbol, attr));
```